# Setting Datomic classpath functions for use by transactor in Windows

Tags: java, windows, clojure, classpath, datomic

I'm trying to set a classpath function to be used by my custom transactor functions as described here: 
https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/database-functions.html#classpath-functions

I have set `DATOMIC_EXT_CLASSPATH` environment variable to path to my .jar file and
added `:requires` to transactor function. Still, when trying to run function I get 
`FileNotFoundException Could not locate some_ns/some_file.clj on classpath` error.

I'm using Windows 8, should I be doing some additional steps? Can I see in Datomic transactor's logs that transactor IS using jar file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the latest version (0.9.5786) there is a bug in which `DATOMIC_EXT_CLASSPATH` is not taken into account in windows scripts. As a workaround I modified `bin\classpath.cmd` file in Datomic distribution by appending `DATOMIC_EXT_CLASSPATH` to `CP_LIST`:

```
@echo off
set CP_LIST=

for %%i in (.\lib\*.jar) do call bin\cpbuild.cmd %%i
for %%i in (.\*transactor*.jar) do call bin\cpbuild.cmd %%i
set CP_LIST=bin;resources;%CP_LIST%;%DATOMIC_EXT_CLASSPATH%
```

With this fix everything works fine